# Difference between two different types of assigning events to event handlers

Tags: c#, events, com

I saw this sample code in SO that was saying one practice is bad and the other one is good. But I don't understand why?
As a matter of fact I am getting that famous  RCW COM object error and that post was saying this could be a reason.

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private Interop.ComObjectWrapper comObject;
    private event ComEventHandler comEventHandler;

    public SomeClass()
    {
        comObject = new Interop.ComObjectWrapper();

        // NO - BAD!
        comObject.SomeEvent += new ComEventHandler(EventCallback);

        // YES - GOOD!
        comEventHandler = new ComEventHandler(EventCallback);
        comObject.SomeEvent += comEventHandler
    }

    public void EventCallback()
    {
        // DO WORK
    }
```

}

Edit: here is the link to the source: [COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567017/com-object-that-has-been-separated-from-its-underlying-rcw-cannot-be-used)

Comment: Could you link to the sample code in question?

Comment: Who is asserting that one is good and one is bad; could you link to where they stated this, if it's public and online?

Comment: I would just do: `comObject.SomeEvent += EventCallback;`.  The `new ComEventHandler` is implied and added automatically by the C# compiler.

Comment: @Servy:  Updated the question with the link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567017/com-object-that-has-been-separated-from-its-underlying-rcw-cannot-be-used

Comment: @BDotA He explains why they're different, and why one is good and one is not.  What problem do you have with that explanation?

Comment: @Servy : well is what he is suggesting correct? if yes : can you please explain it a little in more detail ? and does it only apply to COM event handlers or even for normal .NET object we should do the same?

Comment: @BDotA I can tell you for sure this doesn't make sense for the majority of event handlers; normally doing what he's suggesting would be unneeded bloat.  Not having done any COM work I couldn't say if it's needed in that instance.  In any case, I'd suggest commenting on that answer to ask him to elaborate.

Comment: check out this msdn for if it is needed for non-COM objects (it's not): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366768(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @Servy: I'm not actually sure, that holding references to the delegate in the field will solve an issue with a weak references. Even holding references to the delegate in the comEventHandler field will not not prevent the whole object graph from garbage collection. We still should add additional root for the whole object of type SomeClass to prevent the whole graph from GC.

Comment: It's confusing that the private member `comEventHandler` is an `event`. I think it would be easier to read the code (and simpler) if `comEventHandler` was just a **field**. Maybe even a `readonly` field.

Comment: @SergeyTeplyakov : "We still should add additional root for the whole object of type SomeClass to prevent the whole graph from GC"  .. Thanks, could you please add some code sample of what you think we still need to add ?

Comment: @BDotA see my answer for more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think those two code snippets are the same and we don't have any issues with strong/weak references here.

#### Background

First of all, if our `Interop.ComObjectWrapper` provides CLR event (i.e. event that stores event handlers in delegates) we'll definitely got a strong reference from `ComObjectWrapper` to our object.

Any delegate contains two parts: `Target` of type `object` and Method Pointer to the particular method. If `Target` is `null` than callback points to the static method.

Its impossible to have a delegate with `Target` of type [WeakReference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference.aspx). There is so called [Weak Event Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970850.aspx) but it implements on top of [EventManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh199438.aspx) instead of plain delegates.

### Storing event handler in the field will not help. Part 1

Internal event implementation means that after subscribing to the event:

```
comObject.SomeEvent += EventCallback;
```

`comObject` object implicitely holds an strong reference to the `SomeClass` object. **And this true regardless of what kind of subscribing technique your are using** and whether ComObject is a COM object wrapper or not.

Subscribing to the event adds implicit dependency between two objects in terms of lifetime. That's why the most common memory leak in .NET world caused by subscribing to events of the long-lived objects. **Event subscriber will not die till event holder accessible in the application.**

### Storing event handler in the field will not help. Part 2

But event if my assumption is not true and `ComObjectWrapper` provides some notion of Weak Event Pattern, saving event handler in the field will not help any way.

Lets recap what event keyword mean:

```
private event ComEventHandler comEventHandler;
... 
comEventHandler = new ComEventHandler(EventCallback);
```

Saving callback in current field (and basically we can treat private events as a simple delegate fields) will not change existing behavior.

We already know that delegate is a simple object that stores reference to the Target object (i.e. `SomeClass` object) and a method (i.e. `public void EventCallBack()`). This means that  storing additional delegate in field adds additional reference to the `SomeClass` from the `SomeClass` itself.

Basically, storing event handler in the field semantically equivalent to storing additional reference in SomeClass:

private SomeClass someClass;

public SomeClaas()
{
   // This is basically the same as storing delegate
   // in the comEventHandler field
   someClass = this;
}

**Storing strong reference in the `SomeClass` will not prolong lifetime of the current object.** And this means that if `ComObjectWrapper` will not hold a strong reference to the `SomeClass` object  storing event handler in the `comEventHandler` will not prolong SomeClass's lifetime and will not prevent `SomeClass` from garbage collection.

#### Conclusion

Storing event handler in the private field will not prolong object's lifetime and will not prevent it from garbage collection anyway.

That's why there is no difference between following code snippets in terms of object lifetime:

```
    // GOOD!
    comObject.SomeEvent += new ComEventHandler(EventCallback);

    // EVEN BETTER!
    comObject.SomeEvent += EventCallback;

    // NOT GOOD, BECAUSE WAN'T HELP!
    comEventHandler = new ComEventHandler(EventCallback);
    comObject.SomeEvent += comEventHandler
```

Comment: thank you so much Sergey for the answer. Learned something new. So back to the main problem, you mentioned :"Event subscriber will not die till event holder accessible in the application. "

Could you please suggest some debugging techniques or some sort of solution to this problem on how to locate hte problem and solve it?

Comment: You should take a look at other comments mentioned in this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567017/com-object-that-has-been-separated-from-its-underlying-rcw-cannot-be-used.
To check whether you have an issue with object lifetime you can add instance of this object to the static list of object:
private static List<SomeObject> _neverDyingList = new List<SomeObject>();

// in the method
_neverDyingList.Add(this);

If this don't help that would mean that you have some other issue like Appartment issue or something else.