# Why would I get, "InteropServices.COMException / ForwardCallToInvokeMember" with this code?

Tags: c#, excel-interop, comexception, interopservices, invokemember

After retrieving data and storing it in a generic list, I've got this code to populate an Excel spreadsheet using Excel Interop code:

```
. . .
InitializeExcelObjects();
_currentTopRow = DATA_STARTING_ROW;
foreach (PriceVarianceData _pvd in _pvdList)
{
    AddData(_pvd);
    _currentTopRow = _currentTopRow + 1;
}
. . .

private void AddData(PriceVarianceData _pvd)
{
    var UnitCell = (Excel.Range)_xlSheet.Cells[_currentTopRow, 0];
    UnitCell.Value2 = _pvd.Unit;
    var ShortNameCell = (Excel.Range)_xlSheet.Cells[_currentTopRow, 1];
    ShortNameCell.Value2 = _pvd.ShortName;
    . . .
}
```

It crashes on the first line of the AddData() method (the attempted assignment to UnitCell), with "*System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was unhandled...  StackTrace: at System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember(String memberName, BindingFlags flags, Object...*"

I don't know why this would be; I'm calling this prior to trying to add data:

```
private void InitializeExcelObjects()
{
    _xlApp = new Excel.Application
    {
        SheetsInNewWorkbook = 1,
        StandardFont = "Calibri",
        StandardFontSize = 11
    };
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    //var apartmentSt8 = Thread.CurrentThread.GetApartmentState(); <= STA, as it should be

    _xlBook = _xlApp.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
    _xlSheets = _xlBook.Worksheets;
    _xlSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)_xlSheets.Item[1];
}
```

The full exception is:

*System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146827284
  Message=Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
  Source=""
  ErrorCode=-2146827284
  StackTrace:
       at System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember(String memberName, BindingFlags flags, Object target, Int32[] aWrapperTypes, MessageData& msgData)
       at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range.get__Default(Object RowIndex, Object ColumnIndex)
       at Pivotal.FormMain.AddData(PriceVarianceData _pvd) in c:\Projects\Pivotal\Pivotal\Form1.cs:line 155
       at Pivotal.FormMain.GenerateAndSaveSpreadsheetFile() in c:\Projects\Pivotal\Pivotal\Form1.cs:line 134
       at Pivotal.FormMain.buttonRun_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Projects\Pivotal\Pivotal\Form1.cs:line 77
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       at Pivotal.Program.Main() in c:\Projects\Pivotal\Pivotal\Program.cs:line 19
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:*

What could be the issue here? I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567017/com-object-that-has-been-separated-from-its-underlying-rcw-cannot-be-used), but none of the suggestions seemed to apply to this situation.

### UPDATE

I noticed this morning that I had about 40 Excel processes running, so wondered if that might be the problem (they're not getting shut down/disposed, I guess) and killed them all. I still had the same result, though - and that Excel process also hung around (as could be expected, what with the sudden cessation of execution).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first line of your `AddData()` method you are trying to access the `Cells` with a 0-based index, but the column- and row-indexes in excel are all 1-based indexes (in fact many indexes in Excel are 1-based - but not all).

To fix this you'll have to do 2 things in your case:

1. Ensure that `_currentTopRow` is a 1-based index (i.e. minimum valid value is 1)
2. Change your `AddData()` method as follows:

   ```
   private void AddData(PriceVarianceData _pvd)
   {
       // Note changed column index (from 0 to 1)
       var UnitCell = (Excel.Range)_xlSheet.Cells[_currentTopRow, 1];
       UnitCell.Value2 = _pvd.Unit;

       // Note changed column index (from 1 to 2)
       var ShortNameCell = (Excel.Range)_xlSheet.Cells[_currentTopRow, 2];

       ShortNameCell.Value2 = _pvd.ShortName;
       . . .
   }
   ```

Comment: I surely knew that at one time; half the blame goes to my leaky memory, and the other half to Microsoft's inconsistency in following standards.