# Get deleted Range in Excel

Tags: c#, excel-interop, addin-express

Here's what I am trying to achieve with a Excel Addin. Excel user selects a range and he deletes it. I want to write cell data (whatever he deletes) in that range to a log file. Multiple questions on SO say that you can't get deleted range in SheetChange event handler, you need to store it. I am storing range in a global variable `LastRange` in selection change event method handler. I need `LastRange` in SheetChange event handler.

The problem is I get COM exception --

> COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be
>   used.

I know somewhere that `LastRange` is getting freed and hence the exception.
I referred to another SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567017/com-object-that-has-been-separated-from-its-underlying-rcw-cannot-be-used). Problem persists even though I have strong references to the delegate.

```
private  ADXExcelSheet_EventHandler sheetChangeEventHandler;
private  ADXExcelSheet_EventHandler sheetSelectionChangeEventHandler;

private void InitializeComponent()
{
    sheetChangeEventHandler = new AddinExpress.MSO.ADXExcelSheet_EventHandler(SheetChange);
    excelEvents.SheetChange += sheetChangeEventHandler;
    sheetSelectionChangeEventHandler = new ADXExcelSheet_EventHandler(SheetSelectionChange);
    excelEvents.SheetSelectionChange += sheetSelectionChangeEventHandler;
}

//....

Range LastRange;

public void SheetSelectionChange(object sender, object sheet, object range)
{
    LastRange = (range as Range);
}

public void SheetChange(object sender, object sheet, object range)
{
    ClassX.Method1(range as Range, LastRange);
}
```

Not sure why `LastRange` is still null inside Method1. `LastRange` is correctly passed from SheetChange to `Method1()`. Any other ideas to get this working?

Comment: Is excelEvents something from addinexpress? The Application.SheetSelectionChange event handler is a bit different

Comment: Yes. excelevents is from Addinexpress

Comment: It looks like Add-in Express releases all COM objects passed to an event handler right after the event handler finishes. Any workarounds? I want to store deleted range object and reuse it in a different event handler.

Comment: I confirmed with Add-in express team. Add-in Express releases all COM objects passed to an event handler right after the event handler finishes. Only workaround in this case is, store all rows inside Range object and pass it to Method().

Comment: I don't see any use of the Range if the values are deleted. Range is just a pointer to the location and values. To save the cell data, something like `object LastRangeValue = (range as Range)?.Value`

Answer (score 0):

What about if you make a copy of the range?

```
var sheetConcrete = (Worksheet)sheet;
var rangeConcrete = (Range)range;
LastRange = sheetConcrete.Range[rangeConcrete.Address]
```

(you might need to play with the syntax to get it working)

The add-in should have no way of tracking that COM object, so it should stay alive.

Comment: So what happens when you make a copy? Does it throw an exception when you try to access it?

Comment: Yes, Looks like copied object is invalid.

Comment: Anyway, I figured out the issue here. I am just drafting an answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No probs, glad you got it working. Sometimes all you need is a bit of moral support. I often find that just asking the question makes me think about it more and gets me closer to an answer.