# Set ApartmentState for async void main

Tags: c#, async-await, sta, mta

I have a Windows Forms app.

Now I want to use an `async` method.

Since C# 7.1 I can use an `async Main` method:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7-1

However, now my `STAThread` attribute is ignored and my app runs in MTA. Is this by design or can I force my app to run in STA mode again?

```
/// <summary>
/// The main entry point for the application.
/// </summary>
[STAThread]
private static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    // returns MTA
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ApartmentState);
}
```

Comment: @Evk - you'll get a `ThreadStateException` since, by definition, the current thread has [already started](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.setapartmentstate(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Yes sure, that did not make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this is old, but Damien's answer and the subsequent comment helped me with my issue. I have a console app in which I need to call `async` methods that at some point may need STA execution to use the `OpenFileDialog`.

Here is my resulting code in case it helps others (or just my future self).

**1. Created Extension Method for running thread as STA**

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void RunSTA(this Thread thread)
    {
        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA); // Configure for STA
        thread.Start(); // Start running STA thread for action
        thread.Join(); // Sync back to running thread
    }
}
```

**2. Created `async main` method with `await` to application method (no `[STAThread]` attribute).**

```
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        await App.Get().Run(args);
    }
}
```

**3. Use extension method to wrap `OpenFileDialog` call with STA**

```
public string[] GetFilesFromDialog(string filter, bool? restoreDirectory = true, bool? allowMultiSelect = true)
{
    var results = new string[] { };
    new Thread(() =>
    {
        using (var dialog = new OpenFileDialog())
        {
            dialog.Filter = filter;
            dialog.RestoreDirectory = restoreDirectory ?? true;
            dialog.Multiselect = allowMultiSelect ?? true;
            if (dialog.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
                return; // Nothing selected
            results = dialog.FileNames;
        }
    }).RunSTA();
    return results;
}
```

Comment: This almost got me there but after everything runs I get a `COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used` exception.

Comment: I haven't run into that error before, but this may help (suggests initiating the COM object in each thread): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567017/com-object-that-has-been-separated-from-its-underlying-rcw-cannot-be-used

Comment: It was happening in MS Test when running the test in debug mode. No error otherwise.

Answer (score 10):

An [STA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680112(v=vs.85).aspx) is one in which you promise that a single thread will operate a windows message pump (usually hidden behind a call to [`Application.Run()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.run(v=vs.110).aspx)). You'll run the message pump on your thread when it's not otherwise occupied.

An `async` method is one which, when it's got nothing better to do, will release its thread to go off and do other things.

I can't get those two concepts to align. If you want STA, you want to keep hold of that thread and pump messages. So using `async main` doesn't make sense there.

---

In this particular circumstance (various initialization steps that could benefit from `await` followed by an `Application.Run` I would use the `async Main` *without* the `STAThread` attribute. I would then *explicitly create* an STA thread specifically for then running the windows message loop.

There's no rule that the first thread in your program has to be the/a STA thread and I think this provides the cleanest separation. If your `async Main` has no further useful work to do you may want to share a `TaskCompletionSource` between `Main` and the message-loop-running thread that then signals completion once `Application.Run()` returns.

Comment: To start a STA thread, use this code: `var thread = new Thread(() => DoSomething()); thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);               thread.Start();`

Answer (score 5):

`STAThread` does not work with `async main`.

This is a [known and open issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/22112).

The problem is that the code that transforms `async main` in to a "normal" `main` doesn't copy the attribute over.

Here is [more information](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/97#issuecomment-322819795) specifically about the un-copied attributes.

In [some of the discussion](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/97#issuecomment-322746403) they refer to using a [`SingleThreadedSynchronizationContext`](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/1200#issuecomment-312120851) to allow for async code to be idiomatically used in an STA thread.

Comment: Thanks, suspected this to be a bug, but couldn't find the work item myself.

Comment: @JürgenSteinblock - I'm not sure this is a bug per-se. As I point out, with STA you promise to run a message pump. All variants of `Application.Run` are, by their nature, blocking until the message pump is told to exit - so either you don't call `Application.Run()` (or moral equivalent) and so aren't fulfilling the STA promise or you're going to block anyway and not benefit from `async`.

Comment: @JürgenSteinblock - or, at least, the bug is that the compiler should raise an error if you try to mark an `async main` with `STAThread` rather than copying the attribute.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Well, the issue is marked as `Bug` in the `dotnet/roslyn` repo, so maybe this will be solved somehow. I agree, using `async/await` with the blocking `Application.Run()` does not make sense. But I only used it for code executing before `Run()` and I was not aware that this would change my apps apartement state. A compiler or runtime error would be better than just ignoring the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to reply to https://stackoverflow.com/a/47553573/4640588 but comments don't allow new lines, making the code formatting looked bad.

So based off their post and the helpful link they supplied, in there it showed what the compiler was doing (https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/22112#issuecomment-329462480).
So maybe doing that manually may work.

```
[STAThread]
private static void Main(String[] args)
{
    // normal startup stuff, like Application.EnableVisualStypes();
    MainAsync(args).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}

private static async Task MainAsync(String[] args)
{
    // do stuff
    // can await if want in here
}
```

Comment: It won't work because the MainAsync is still executed asynchronously. Creating a Thread with `SetApartmentState` works. I wrapped it in an extension method so I can do `await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => .., ApartmentState.STA)`